# How can I get the integers in a stringstream and add them into an array?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I don't want just the first one, I want them all. How can I do this? I always get either nothing or the first value only and I've been converting the stringstream into a string. Is there a way to get it directly from stringstream? The ints are separated by semicolons.

Comment: Do you know how many integers are in the stringstream before creating the array? Are you able to use `std::vector`?

Comment: I know how to use vector, and I know how many int there are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::vector`, and, if you know the number of ints before-hand, you could use `reserve` to improve performance. Since you're using semi-colons as delimiters, one solution would be to use this delimiter with `std::getline`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss{"1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10"};
    std::vector<int> ints;

    // Reserve space for 10 integers:
    ints.reserve(10);

    std::string temp;
    while (std::getline(ss, temp, ';'))
        ints.push_back(std::stoi(temp));

    for (int i : ints)
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry, but that doesn't work. Also, I have them separated by semicolons in the stringstream.

Comment: @JCoder: you really should have mentioned that.

Comment: I didn't think it would make a difference since it's getting ints, not strings.... sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Thats just simply using copy and iteratrs.

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
void func(std::istream& stream, std::array<int, SIZE>& arr)
{
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(stream), SIZE, std::begin(arr));
}
```

But rater than thinking about arrays you should think about using iterator. That way you can use any container types.

```
template<typename I>
void func(std::istream& stream, I dst)
{
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(stream),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              dst);
}
```

You also mention vector in the comments:

```
void func(std::istream& stream, std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(stream),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              std::back_inserter(vector)
             );
}
```

Now you mention that your numbers are comma seporated. To cope with this you can defined a class that reads a number and a trailing comma;

```
struct NumberAndComma
{
    int   number;
    operator int() {return number;}
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, NumberAndComma& data)
    {
        if (str >> number) {
            char x;
            stream >> x;
            if (x != ',') {
                stream.unget();
            }
            if (!stream) {
                // It was good before we tried to read comma.
                // so really it should still be good even if there is no comma
                stream.clear();
            }
        }
        return stream;
    }
};
```

Now you can use this inplace of int above:

```
void func(std::istream& stream, std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<NumberAndComma>(stream),
              std::istream_iterator<NumberAndComma>(),
              std::back_inserter(vector)
             );
}
```